# How can I split the string by <br> into a list using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, list, selenium, selenium-webdriver, split

My string when printed looks like:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

as it's a extracted with selenium and it looks in html:

```
line1
<br>
line2
<br>
line3
<br>
```

I want to transform that string to list of 3 elements, i tried the following:

```
List<String> test= new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(mystring.split("<br>")));
```

but it did not work i got a list of 1 element as follows:

```
[line1
line2
line3]
```

Comment: this should just work Arrays.asList(mystring.split("<br>") without additional external ArrayList.

Comment: Use `.split("</?br>")`

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays.asList
```

already returns the list, no need to wrap it once again.

```
List<String> test= Arrays.asList(mystring.split("<br>"));
```

Comment: that did not work, i printed : System.out.println(Arrays.toString(test.toArray())); and got the same result

Answer (score 0):

you can use Arrays.asList directly as follow

```
List<String> result = Arrays.asList(myString.split("<br>"));
```

But the List we get has a limit,this list is Unmodifiable, if you want to do

```
result.add("element");
```

you will get an UnsupportedOperationException

if you want to modify your list as follow,you can get it such as

```
String[] split = myString.split("<br>");
List<String> result = Arrays.stream(split).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

you can get a modifiable list.

Answer (score 0):

To `split()` the *text* by `<br>` and place into a [list](/questions/tagged/list) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `visibilityOfElementLocated()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *cssSelector* and `split()`:

  ```
  String[] cssParts = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("parentElementCssSelector"))).getText().split("<br>");
  System.out.println(cssParts);
  ```
- Using *xpath* and `split()`:

  ```
  String[] xpathParts = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("parentElementXpath"))).getText().split("<br>");
  System.out.println(xpathParts);
  ```

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to extract the text 73 from the text 1-16 of 73 results from the search result summary within https://www.amazon.com using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63058912/how-to-extract-the-text-73-from-the-text-1-16-of-73-results-from-the-search-resu/63060153#63060153)